# def in python not working when called

Tags: python, function

```
import pyttsx 
import random
import os  
import serial
import webbrowser

while True:
    def portport():
        ser = serial.Serial('COM3',9600) 
        raw_data = ser.read(7)
        msg = str(raw_data[3:6])
        print msg
        ser.close()

    engine = pyttsx.init()
    portport()
    if(msg == 'mof'):
            engine.say('Are you sure?')   
            engine.runAndWait()          
            portport()
            if(msg == 'yes'):
                engine.say('Chrome has now closed')
                os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM chrome.exe")
                engine.runAndWait()

            elif(msg == 'noo'):
                engine = pyttsx.init()
                engine.say('Are you kidding me?')
                engine.runAndWait()

    if(msg == 'hi_'):
            greeting()
    if(msg == 'bye'):
            leaving()
    if(msg == 'who'):
            engine = pyttsx.init()
            engine.say('Hi there')
            engine.runAndWait()

    if(msg == 'lik'):
           engine = pyttsx.init()
           engine.say('Ofcourse I do!')
           engine.runAndWait()
```

My problem is that everything works if instead of creating a def (`portport()` ) and call it when I need it, I just write my code which is included in this def. I used (but didn't put in here because I don't want it to be a very long piece of code) other functions (for example `greeting()` ) and it worked just fine.

Eclipse's console when using the code as above "says":

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\eclipse\workspace\Ai_Project\Ai\Ai_Brain.py", line 126, in <module>
    if(msg == 'mof'):
NameError: name 'msg' is not defined
```

And every single `if(msg == 'something'):` turns red

I have read a lot of posts here and everywhere but can't seem to be a python function problem

**THE ANSWER:**
Thank you all for your valuable answers and a little bit more for mhawke's answer.
The code worked after the chances which had to be made according to your suggestions. For future use the updated code is:

```
.....

    def portport():

            ser = serial.Serial('COM3',9600) 
            raw_data = ser.read(7)
            msg = str(raw_data[3:6])
            print msg
            ser.close()
            return msg

    while True:

            engine = pyttsx.init() 

            msg = portport()

             if(msg == 'mof'):
                        engine.say('Are you sure?')   
                        engine.runAndWait()          
                        msg = portport()

                        if(msg == 'yes'):
                            engine.say('Chrome has now closed')
                            os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM chrome.exe")
                            engine.runAndWait()

                        elif(msg == 'noo'):
                            engine = pyttsx.init()
                            engine.say('Are you kidding me?')
                            engine.runAndWait()
                                                                      ......
```

Comment: `msg` is declared and initialized outside of its usage scope. Be careful to indentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when using the function, `msg` is a *local* variable of `portport()`. The variable is not available outside of the function. Therefore the references to it from outside the function cause the `NameError` exception.

When declared in line `msg` has the same scope as the references to it in the `if` statements, so there is no problem.

One way to correct this when using the function is to have the function *return* the value of `msg`:

```
def portport():
    ser = serial.Serial('COM3',9600) 
    raw_data = ser.read(7)
    msg = str(raw_data[3:6])
    print msg
    ser.close()
    return msg
```

Then call `portport()` and assign the return value to the variable `msg`:

```
msg = portport()
```

Now a new variable `msg` is created in the same scope as the `if` statements that reference it.

N.B. do not confuse the `msg` inside the function with that outside the function - they are different variables because they exist in different scopes.

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable answers and a little bit more for mhawke's answer.

Answer (score 1):

`msg` is only defined within the `portport` function. If you want to use it outside, you need to return it from there, and assign it to a local variable.

Note, you should not have your function definition within the while loop.

```
def portport():
    ser = serial.Serial('COM3',9600) 
    raw_data = ser.read(7)
    msg = str(raw_data[3:6])
    print msg
    ser.close()
    return msg

while True:
    engine = pyttsx.init()
    msg = portport()
    if msg == 'mof':
        ...
```

Also note, you don't need parentheses around conditions in Python.

Comment: Parentheses is a necessary bad habit for other programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

`msg` is local variable in `portport()` and hence not accessible outside.

Answer (score 0):

Your msg variable is not in the correct scope.

```
import pyttsx 
import random
import os  
import serial
import webbrowser

while True:


    def portport():

        ser = serial.Serial('COM3',9600) 
        raw_data = ser.read(7)
        msg = str(raw_data[3:6])
        print msg
        ser.close()
        return msg

    engine = pyttsx.init()

    msg = portport()

    if(msg == 'mof'):

            engine.say('Are you sure?')   

            engine.runAndWait()          

            portport()

            if(msg == 'yes'):

                engine.say('Chrome has now closed')

                os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM chrome.exe")

                engine.runAndWait()


            elif(msg == 'noo'):

                engine = pyttsx.init()

                engine.say('Are you kidding me?')

                engine.runAndWait()

    if(msg == 'hi_'):

            greeting()

    if(msg == 'bye'):

            leaving()     

    if(msg == 'who'):

            engine = pyttsx.init()
            engine.say('Hi there')
            engine.runAndWait()

    if(msg == 'lik'):

           engine = pyttsx.init()
           engine.say('Ofcourse I do!')
           engine.runAndWait()
```